# Conflicts between data write with useEffect in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to initialize an array in a parent structure from its children. I currently have the solution below, however the two useEffect calls overwrite each other, and the output of `errors` is "{"2":0}", where I want it to be "{"1":0, "2":0}.

I don't want to initialize `errors` in the Parent structure as I would need to write multiple twice the same code for initialization (I optimally would only append the new child structures and the error array should be changed). Is it possible to do?

Thanks.

Parent.js:

```js
export default function Parent(props){
   const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({});
   return <React.Component>
           <Child errors=errors setErrors=setErrors identifier="1"/>
           <Child errors=errors setErrors=setErrors identifier="2"/>
          {JSON.stringify(errors)}
          </React.Component>
}
```

Child.js:

```js
export default function Child(props){
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setErrors({...props.errors, [props.identifier]:0});
    }, []);
   return <React.Component>
          </React.Component>
}
```

Comment: This architecture feels wrong to me, what UI are you trying to achieve and where do the errors come from? do the come from the components?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, you can't pass props that way.

Comment: @SimonLaux Parent is a form, while each Child is an input field. I'm keeping the validation on the child part (updating the error onChange of each child), and propagating it back to the parent for global validation of the form. Do you have a better idea for the architecture?

Comment: there are form libraries for react, I would recommend trying https://react-hook-form.com before developing an own solution for the problem. And if you do your own solution, then I think it's better to move the validation also to the parent or even to a react context to bring data, validation and errors to one single place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to `setErrors` to update the value given the previous state.

```js
props.setErrors(prev => ({...prev, [props.identifier]: 0}));
```

See the [documentation for `set` functions from `useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate):

> If you pass a function as nextState, it will be treated as an updater function. It must be pure, should take the pending state as its only argument, and should return the next state. React will put your updater function in a queue and re-render your component. During the next render, React will calculate the next state by applying all of the queued updaters to the previous state.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the callback for setting the state in this case:

Child.js:

```js
export default function Child(props){
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setErrors((previousErrors)=> {...previousErrors, [props.identifier]:0});
    }, []);
   return <React.Component>
          </React.Component>
}
```